# Transposing Rows to Columns in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, transpose

I've trawling the internet to make sense of how to do what I want to do, but to no avail. I need to transpose the data below....

```
Caption=C:
Description=Local Fixed Disk
DriveType=3
FreeSpace=41265664000
ProviderName=
Size=146056146944
VolumeName=
Caption=D:
Description=Local Fixed Disk
DriveType=3
FreeSpace=125067259904
ProviderName=
Size=1073738674176
VolumeName=Data
Caption=E:
Description=Removable Disk
DriveType=2
FreeSpace=
ProviderName=
Size=
VolumeName=
```

To a table layout, like this...

```
Caption   Description        DriveType   FreeSpace     ProviderName   Size            VolumeName 
C:        Local Fixed Disk   3           41265664000                  146056146944     
D:        Local Fixed Disk   3           125067259904                 1073738674176   Data 
E:        Removable Disk     2
```

In `bash`. I've been exploring a myriad of `awk` scripts but I don't seem to understand the logic behind them that well :|

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to use `bash`, `sed` or `awk` here? These problems can be easily solved using `perl` or `python`

Comment: `bash`,`sed` and `awk` is just the path I started on. If there are better tools/solutions I'm happy to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

with `gawk`:

```
awk -v RS="Caption" -F"[=\n\"]" '
    NR==2{
        printf RS;
        for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2){
            printf ":"$i
        };
        print ""
    };
    {
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){
        if ($i != "" ) printf ":"$i;
        else printf ": "
    };
    print ""}'  file | column -s":" -t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use other tools to do this such as `Perl` or `python`.

In Perl for example you could use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
use Text::ASCIITable;

next unless /^(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/;
$data{$1} = [] if not $data{$1};
push $data{$1}, $2;

END {
    $t = Text::ASCIITable->new();
    $t->setCols(keys %data);

    for my $i (0..@{$data{(keys %data)[0]}} - 1) {
        $t->addRow(map $data{$_}[$i], keys %data)
    }
    print $t;
}
```

Your data can be in the `data.txt` so you can write:

```
$ ./myscript.pl data.txt
.---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
| Caption | Size          | DriveType | VolumeName | FreeSpace    | Description      | ProviderName |
+---------+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+
| C:      |  146056146944 |         3 |            |  41265664000 | Local Fixed Disk |              |
| D:      | 1073738674176 |         3 | Data       | 125067259904 | Local Fixed Disk |              |
| E:      |               |         2 |            |              | Removable Disk   |              |
'---------+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------+------------------+--------------'
```

This script is generic for **N** number of columns given in any order. However,  if the columns are known and displayed always in the same order the code can be simplified to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
use Text::ASCIITable;

BEGIN {
    @columns = qw/Caption Description DriveType FreeSpace ProviderName Size VolumeName/;
    $t = Text::ASCIITable->new();
    $t->setCols(@columns);
    $re = join "\n", map "$_=(?<$_>.*)", @columns;
    undef $/;
}

$t->addRow(map $+{$_}, @columns) while(/$re/g);

END { print $t; }
```

Or even in Python if you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from terminaltables import AsciiTable
table_data = []
for row in ["Caption" + d for d in sys.stdin.read().split("Caption")[1:]]:
    table_data.append([column.split('=')[1] for column in row.split("\n")[:-1]])
    columns = [column.split('=')[0] for column in row.split("\n")[:-1]]

table_data.insert(0, columns)
print AsciiTable(table_data).table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }
{ hdr = hdr sep $1; data = data sep $2; sep=OFS }
$1=="VolumeName" { if (!c++) print hdr; print data; data=sep="" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s= -t
Caption  Description       DriveType  FreeSpace     ProviderName  Size           VolumeName
C:       Local Fixed Disk  3          41265664000                 146056146944
D:       Local Fixed Disk  3          125067259904                1073738674176  Data
E:       Removable Disk    2
```